# Calculation of minimum calorie consumption rate required to burn off 300 over a 5km row.

Tags: calculus

The rowing machine I use gives a real time calories/hour rate as I row.
When I row over 5km I aim to burn a minimum of 300 calories over the 5km distance.

How to I calculate the minimum calories/hour that I need to maintain to burn 300 calories over the 5km. Experience shows that it must be a value in-excess of 800 calories/hour, but how do I calculated this.

Intuitively I thought this was a fairly simple question to answer, however thus far I've not nailed it.

Any wisdom very gratefully accepted.

Comment: If you knew the rowing speed, you could multiply that with the calories per hour. Then the units would become
$$
\frac{\text{calories}}{\text{km}} \cdot 
\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} = 
\frac{\text{calories}}{\text{h}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I really have no idea of the velocity. Is there not some clever way to calculate the calories/hour directly? So would successive approximation be the only way to get there?

Comment: You burn a minimum of $300 \text{ calories}$ over $5 \text{ km}$, so (if this trend continues) you should burn a minimum of $800\text{ calories}$ over $13.33\ldots \text{ km}$. Do you row over $13.33\ldots \text{ km}$ each hour?